gazebo is pushing out an object from inside another hollow object that i created from .dae mesh (a pipeline)
I want to simulate a robot moving inside a pipeline. I exported the .dae file a very simple pipeline mesh from blender. the collision happens when the ball (for simplicity) hits pipeline from outside. but when I put the ball inside the pipeline it is pushed outside the pipeline.

>  1. <?xml version='1.0'?> <sdf version='1.7'>   <model
>     name='my_pipeline1'>
>         <link name='pipeline'>
>           <inertial>
>             <mass>1000</mass>
>             <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
>             <inertia>
>               <ixx>1</ixx>
>               <ixy>0</ixy>
>               <ixz>0</ixz>
>               <iyy>1</iyy>
>               <iyz>0</iyz>
>               <izz>1</izz>
>             </inertia>
>           </inertial>
>           <self_collide>1</self_collide>
>           <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
>           <kinematic>0</kinematic>
>           <pose>0 0 1 1.5708 -0 0</pose>
>           <gravity>1</gravity>
>           <visual name='pipe_visual'>
>             <geometry>
>               <mesh>
>                 <uri>model://my_pipeline/media/my_pipeline_0.dae</uri>
>               </mesh>
>             </geometry>
>             <material>
>               <shader type='pixel'>
>                 <normal_map>__default__</normal_map>
>               </shader>
>               <script>
>                 <name>ModelPreview_1::pipeline::pipe_visual_MATERIAL_</name>
>                 <uri>__default__</uri>
>               </script>
>               <ambient>0 0 0 1</ambient>
>               <diffuse>0 0 0 1</diffuse>
>               <specular>0 0 0 1</specular>
>               <emissive>0 0 0 1</emissive>
>             </material>
>             <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
>             <transparency>0</transparency>
>             <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
>           </visual>
>           <collision name='collision_base'>
>             <laser_retro>0</laser_retro>
>             <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
>             <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
>             <geometry>
>               <mesh>
>                 <uri>/home/sepid/.gazebo/models/my_pipeline/media/my_pipeline_0.dae</uri>
>                 <scale>1 1 1</scale>
>               </mesh>
>             </geometry>
>             <surface>
>               <friction>
>                 <ode>
>                   <mu>1</mu>
>                   <mu2>1</mu2>
>                   <fdir1>0 0 0</fdir1>
>                   <slip1>0</slip1>
>                   <slip2>0</slip2>
>                 </ode>
>                 <torsional>
>                   <coefficient>1</coefficient>
>                   <patch_radius>0</patch_radius>
>                   <surface_radius>0</surface_radius>
>                   <use_patch_radius>1</use_patch_radius>
>                   <ode>
>                     <slip>0</slip>
>                   </ode>
>                 </torsional>
>               </friction>
>               <bounce>
>                 <restitution_coefficient>0</restitution_coefficient>
>                 <threshold>1e+06</threshold>
>               </bounce>
>               <contact>
>                 <collide_without_contact>0</collide_without_contact>
>                 <collide_without_contact_bitmask>1</collide_without_contact_bitmask>
>                 <collide_bitmask>1</collide_bitmask>
>                 <ode>
>                   <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
>                   <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
>                   <kp>1e+13</kp>
>                   <kd>1</kd>
>                   <max_vel>0.01</max_vel>
>                   <min_depth>0</min_depth>
>                 </ode>
>                 <bullet>
>                   <split_impulse>1</split_impulse>
>                   <split_impulse_penetration_threshold>-0.01</split_impulse_penetration_threshold>
>                   <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
>                   <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
>                   <kp>1e+13</kp>
>                   <kd>1</kd>
>                 </bullet>
>               </contact>
>             </surface>
>           </collision>
>         </link>
>         <static>1</static>
>         <allow_auto_disable>1</allow_auto_disable>   </model> </sdf>



Is there a reason for the block quote formatting (and the "1.")? I've fixed the code formatting for you - you were using the wrong character (use \`` and not ') - but I left the >and the1.` as I wasn't sure of your intent.

I solved it by editing the mesh of the pipeline. I flipped the normal of the surface inwards in Blender, that way light reflection and collision reflection turned inside.
Now the pipeline is seen only from inside and the robot stays inside the pipeline.
